# Override spring bean definition

Tags: java, spring

I have to import xml based configuration from old library. I have there one bean with `@PostConstruct` method which takes very long time to finish (lookup records from database).

Is it posiible to use `@ImportResource` to load xml configuration and somehow override this one bean definiotion?
I know that I can create different bean in my context but spring still will execute `@PostConstruct` on the old one.

Also I can't change sources in the legacy library.

Comment: Do you have access to the `xml` bean definitions? if so, you could duplicate it and make the necessary changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to do this, you might want to look at the BeanFactoryPostProcessor hook. See here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factory-postprocessors

However you will be tweaking the way the container behaves which should be done with caution.